# Real life class imbalance

Tags: classification, dataset, unbalanced-classes, text-mining, accuracy

Fellow like-minded people,

I'm writing my thesis in fake news detection on scrapped twitter data and facing an issue (among many others). Fake news consist of less than 10% of the total tweets or news content (during events), which means that there is a valid real-life class imbalance. I know there are models that respond well to such imbalances and I also have the choice of building my own training and validation set.

**Question**: Given the real life class imbalance, would my models benefit from keeping the huge class imbalance proportions in the data or should I build something more balanced? I understand what the accuracy paradox is, confusion matrix and such, but what is your say?

Comment: [Are unbalanced datasets problematic, and (how) does oversampling (purport to) help?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/357466/1352)

Comment: Thank you, Stephan. The links shed light on the matter and a few other questions. I see this as a win.